# Perl Checking if a scalar contains one of the elements in an array

Tags: perl

I have an array

```
my @array = qw/FOO BAR BAZ/;
```

and a scalar read from a file containing data like

```
+++123++585+++FOO
```

or

```
+++589++458+++XYZ
```

I am looking for a nice way to check if an element of the array matches part of the input string.

I know I could just loop over the array and match that way but was wondering if there is  a more perl like way.

Comment: regular expression? yes?

Comment: `do{if($str=~m/$_/){print "YES!"; print; print "\n"}} for @array`

Comment: @loldop, OP did say that they preferred a way that does not involve looping over an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a regex that matches all of the @array:

```
my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, @array;
$string =~ $regex;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is far better way. You can construct regular expression. It will be alternatives of fixed strings which is fortunately translated into trie (Aho-Corasick) which leads into linear search time. It is the most efficient way at all.

```
my @array = qw/FOO BAR BAZ/;
my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, @array;
$re = qr/$re/;

for my $string (@strings) {
  if ($string =~ $re) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what [grep](http://p3rl.org/grep) is for. Here's a small snippet:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "+++123++585+++FOO";
my $blank = "+++123++585+++XYZ";
my @array = qw/FOO BAR BAZ/;
print grep {$str =~ $_} @array, "\n";
print grep {$blank =~ $_} @array, "\n";
```

This would just return:

```
FOO
```

`grep`, `reduce` and `map` are what we call higher order functions in FP world, though `reduce` might be called `fold` there. Have a look at MJD's Higher Order Perl for more of these.

- [grep](http://p3rl.org/grep)
- [map](http://p3rl.org/map)
- [reduce](http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/Scalar-List-Utils-1.27/lib/List/Util.pm)
- [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/)

Comment: `grep`, `map`, and `reduce` imply a loop that is quite unneccessary here, although your knowledge of HOP is laudable.

Comment: While I agree that `grep`, `map` and `reduce` are essentially loop iterations under the hood, I can see how my solution is less than optimal. That said, OP did want a solution that looked more perlish. I'll let this answer be as a reminder to give considered answers and not halfbaked ones.